# Angular: Simplify the "providers" when lots of services are required

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that relies on several supporting services, which the parent component will "provide" in its providers array.

If I have several services that are required, I'm having to add all of them into the providers array, and make sure they're all injected in the constructor, even though they may not even used by this parent component directly.

```
providers: [
    ServiceA,
    ServiceB,
    ServiceC,
    ServiceD
]
...
constructor(
    private $sa: ServiceA,
    private $sb: ServiceB,
    private $sc: ServiceC,
    private $sd: ServiceD
)
```

Is there a way to wrap these services into another service that will be provided? or combine the providing of these services another way?

Ideally, I could have a "controller" service which encapsulates all these other services and only exposes what's necessary to the parent, then the parent would just have to provide this "controller".

```
providers: [ControllerService]
...
constructor(private $cont: ControllerService)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: See https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services . Just decorate your services with: providedIn: 'root' will be enough, no providers array needed. You could make a container service importing other services but I would not recommend it. Mainly to prevent importing unused services and to have some meaningful naming of services in your importing component

Comment: @user3791775 Thank you for commenting, but the problem is I don't want these services to be provided in the root; I don't want singleton instances for these services. I need a new local instance each time the component is used.

Comment: Then you would be better off to use plain classes (no angular services/Injectable). Just do this.myNonSingleTonService = new myPlainTypescriptClass() in your constructor

Comment: @user3791775 I see - that may be a strong solution. I'll look into this further. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to join all those services in one modulo and import it into your component module. A possible structure can be this

```
services/
    |-one.service.ts
    |-two.service.ts
    |-three.service.ts
    |-four.service.ts
    |-services.module.ts
your-module/
    |-your-component.component.css
    |-your-component.component.html
    |-your-component.component.ts
    |-your-module.module.ts
app.component.css
app.component.html
app.component.ts
app.module.ts
```

In this example you have four service and the services.module.ts that can looks as follow

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { OneService } from './one.service.ts'
import { TwoService } from './two.service.ts'
import { ThreeService } from './three.service.ts'
import { FourService } from './four.service.ts'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers : [
    OneService,
    TwoService,
    ThreeService,
    FourService
  ]
})
export class ServicesModule { }
export * from './one.service';
export * from './two.service';
export * from './three.service';
export * from './four.service';
```

Then in your-moudle.module.ts

```
import { ServiceModule } from '../services/services.module';
...
...
imports : [
    ...
    ...
    ServiceModule
]
...
...
```

and finally in your-component.component.ts

```
import { OneService, TwoService, ThreeService, FourService } from '../../services/services.module'
...
...

    constructor(
        private _oneService : OneService,
        private _twoService : TwoService,
        private _threeService : ThreeService,
        private _fourService : FourService
    ) {}
...
...
```

Also you can add an alias to your tsconfig.json to avoid relative paths

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@services" : [
        "app/services/services.module.ts"
      ],
    },
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

and then you can import the services as follow

```
import { OneService, TwoService, ThreeService, FourService } from '@services'
```

Hope this can help you.